# Is the order of results of re.findall guaranteed?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Will the list of matches returned by `re.findall` always be in the same order as they are in the source text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, as stated in the `re` module [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.

So, **yes** - the list of matches returned by `re.findall` will always be in the same order as in the source text.

Comment: Beat you to it by 15 seconds :)