# How should I make these regex capture groups more succinct?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm using python's `re` library to do this, but it's a basic regex question.

I am receiving a string of coordinate information in degrees-minutes-seconds format without spaces, and I'm parsing it out to discrete coordinate pairs for conversion.

The string is fed to me looking like this (fake coords for example):

`102030N0102030E203040N0203040E304050N0304050E405060N0405060E`

I am catching it like this:

```
coordstr = '102030N0102030E203040N0203040E304050N0304050E405060N0405060E'

coords = re.match(
    re.compile(r"^(\d+[NS]{1}\d+[EW]{1})(\d+[NS]{1}\d+[EW]{1})(\d+[NS]{1}\d+[EW]{1})(\d+[NS]{1}\d+[EW]{1})"),
    coordstr)

for x in coords.groups():
    print(x)
```

which gives me

```
102030N0102030E
203040N0203040E
304050N0304050E
405060N0405060E
```

And allows me to address each coordinate pair as `coords.group(1)`, `coords.group(2)` and so on.

So it works, but it feels like I'm being too verbose in the pattern.  Is there a more succinct way to crawl the line with one of the capture groups, and add each matched group to `.groups()` as it's encountered?  I know I could do it with brute force string slicing but that seems like more trouble than it's worth.

I've read [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) but it doesn't seem to address what I'm going after in this question.

Because this is for an enterprise and these strings describe raster bounds, I will be validating the string before introducing the regex search and falling back to a `gdal` object if the string is not found (or corrupted).

Comment: Does `re.findall(r'\d+[NS]\d+[EW]', coordstr)` work well enough? It just matches all occurrences in a string. Or, do you need to also *pre-validate* the string, and only extract four parts if the string matches this specific format?

Comment: That worked great.  Can I rely on the order to be maintained each time?  Because this is for an enterprise and these strings describe raster bounds, I will be validating the string before introducing the regex search and falling back to a `gdal` object if the string is not found (or corrupted).

Comment: Yes. See [Is the order of results of re.findall guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133436/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will pre-validate the strings you will process with regex, you need not use `re.search` / `re.match` with several groups with identical pattern, you can use `re.findall` to get all `\d+[NS]\d+[EW]` pattern matches from your strings:

```py
import re
coordstr = '102030N0102030E203040N0203040E304050N0304050E405060N0405060E'
coords = re.findall(r'\d+[NS]\d+[EW]', coordstr)
for x in coords:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
102030N0102030E
203040N0203040E
304050N0304050E
405060N0405060E
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DxsTVx).

**NOTE**: the list of matches returned by re.findall will always be in the same order as they are in the source text, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133436/3832970).